# UWP View Layout based on Navigation Path

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have a page that can be accessed by a button in two seperate views. My issue is that when I Navigate to the page from the first view I want to set the visibility of a button within that page to collapse. When I navigate to the page from the other view I need that particular button to be set to Visible.

So pretty much I am wondering if there is a way to set the visibility property of a button in a view from outside that particular view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Navigate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_NavigationTransitionInfo_) method allows you to pass a parameter to be interpreted by the target of the navigation. Details for how to do please reference [Pass information between pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages).

You could pass the `Visibility` property through `Navigate` method and receive it with `OnNavigateTo` method in the page, then you could set this property to the button inside this page. For example:

```
//When navigate
private void btnnavigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(testpage), "Collapsed");
}
```

And on the page :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter is string && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)e.Parameter))
    {
        var visibleproperty = e.Parameter as string;
        if(visibleproperty=="Collapsed")
        {
            btnnavigate.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I thought that I may be able to pass the parameter through on navigate. I just couldn't make it work correctly, this is gong to help me immensely. Thank you